# How can I redirect to function controller after registration in laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I hope you can help me, I wanna customize the `registercontroller` from Laravel, I have this, but after the user is registered send me a JSON of data, how can I do for don't send me the JSON and redirect to the `HomeController`.
Thanks.
PD. Sorry for my English.

```php
    public function register(Request $request)
        {
          $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'nombre' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255','unique:users'],
                'telefono' => ['required', 'numeric', 'max:99999999', 'min:00000000'],
                'direccion' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'sueldo' => ['numeric','min:0.01','max:0.99'],
                //'foto' => ['string', 'max:255'],
                'email' => ['string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
                'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:4', 'confirmed'],
              ]);
    
            if ($request->hasFile('foto')) {
              $request = request();
              $file = $request->file('foto');
              $nom_imagen = time().".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
              $upload_path = 'imagenes/';
              $profile_image_url = $upload_path . $nom_imagen;
              $success = $file->move($upload_path, $nom_imagen);
    
            } else  {
                $nom_imagen = '';
            }
            return User::create([
                'name' => $request->input('name'),
                'nombre' => $request->input('nombre'),
                'telefono' => $request->input('telefono'),
                'direccion' => $request->input('direccion'),
                'sueldo' => $request->input('sueldo'),
                'email' => $request->input('email'),
                'foto' => $nom_imagen,
                'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
                return redirect()->action('HomeController@index'),
            ]);
        }
```

[Laravel 5.5: Execute a method before registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154625/laravel-5-5-execute-a-method-before-registration#)

HomeController

```php
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
    class HomeController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }
    
        /**
         * Show the application dashboard.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
         */
        public function index()
        {
            return view('index');
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's already answered in the link you provided, you should read more careful. Don't return `User::create` and move your redirect out of the `User::create`

Comment: your redirect statement are missplaced, put it outside the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the return value of `User::create()` which will be a User object which gets converted to json when returned as a response.

Also since your HomeController is protected by 'auth' middleware you need to login the user before redirecting to '/home'

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'nombre' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255','unique:users'],
        'telefono' => ['required', 'numeric', 'max:99999999', 'min:00000000'],
        'direccion' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'sueldo' => ['numeric','min:0.01','max:0.99'],
         //'foto' => ['string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:4', 'confirmed'],
    ]);

    if ($request->hasFile('foto')) {
        $request = request();
        $file = $request->file('foto');
        $nom_imagen = time().".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $upload_path = 'imagenes/';
        $profile_image_url = $upload_path . $nom_imagen;
        $success = $file->move($upload_path, $nom_imagen);

    } else  {
        $nom_imagen = '';
    }

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'nombre' => $request->input('nombre'),
        'telefono' => $request->input('telefono'),
        'direccion' => $request->input('direccion'),
        'sueldo' => $request->input('sueldo'),
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'foto' => $nom_imagen,
        'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
    ]);

    Auth::guard()->login($user);

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Comment: You may mark the answer as accepted for the benefit of subsequent visitors

Comment: I already did, thanks Im only mark up row

Answer (score -1):

Move the redirect after create user , try like this

```
 User::create([ 
   'name' => $request->input('name'),
   'nombre' =>$request->input('nombre'),
   'telefono' => $request->input('telefono'), 
  'direccion' => $request->input('direccion'), 
   'sueldo' => $request->input('sueldo'), 
   'email' => $request->input('email'), 
   'foto' => $nom_imagen,
   'password' => Hash::make($request['password'])
 ]);

return redirect()->action('HomeController@index'),
```

Comment: don't redirect, I did this 'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        ]);
        return redirect()->action('HomeController@index');
    } but after create show me the json

Comment: Please share your index methods

Comment: of Homecontroller?

Comment: Yes, method index of HomeController

Comment: I already did, but the homecontroller its intact, don't overwrite

Comment: Oc it doesn't redirect, it `return`s the created user before redirecting